# Mongoose compound index creation fields order

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a question regarding compound index creation in mongodb:
Say I want to create this compound index:

```
cSchema.index({account:1, authorization: 1, c_type: 1});
```

Problem is, javascript doesn't guarantee dictionary order, so I won't be sure the compound index is in the order I want.

How can I make sure it's indeed `{account:1, authorization:1, c_type:1}` in that order ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simple answer is that most abuse the behaviour that simple String properties that don't parse to an integer on an Object will enumerate in creation order. Although [not guaranteed in ES2015 for some enumeration methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38218582), it does work in a confined environment like Node/V8. This has worked in most JS engines for a while now but had never been part of the ES spec before ES2015.

### MongoDB

The underlying MongoDB driver [`createIndex`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#createIndex) function supports `String`, `Array` and `Object` index definitions. The parsing code is in a util function called [`parseIndexOptions`](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/d81d88c12f8a3c2876da6df76fd81ed0b15595fa/lib/utils.js#L187).

If you specify an array of Strings, Array pairs, or Objects then the order will be fixed:

```
['location','type']
[['location', '2d'],['type', 1]]
[{location: '2d'},{type: 1}]
```

Also note that the [`createIndex`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#createIndex) code does use `Object.keys` to enumerate when it gets an `Object` of index properties.

### Mongoose

The [`Schema#index`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema-index) function is documented as requiring an Object to pass to "MongoDB driver's `createIndex()` function" so looks to support passing through whatever options you provide.

There are a couple of places where indexes are further processed though. For example when you create a sub document with an index, the index [needs to have the parent schema prefixed onto field names](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/ed617b13af3915c7ade2e5817c6c46c7aedd452a/lib/schema.js#L1437-L1463). On a quick glance I think this code still works with an Array but I can't see any tests for that in the Mongoose code so you might want to confirm it yourself.

Mongoose does have a [compound index test that relies on Object property order](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/67c465aac5c864c3004d11d49934605037c8f520/test/model.indexes.test.js#L152-L172).